# Cannot run setup:di:compile, generated directory file permissions

Tags: magento2

I am trying to set up a local instance of Magento. However, when I try to run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` I get the following error:

```
  Class Magento\Cron\Model\DeadlockRetrierInterface does not exist
  Class Wyomind\CronScheduler\Plugin\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated' directory permission is
  read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you mu
  st add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.
```

It seems the problem is that the generated directory file permissions are read only but I have run `chmod -R 777 generated`, when I run `ls -la` it shows this directory permissions are `drwxrwxrwx`. I've run all kinds of permissions commands from other answers and from the Magento Docs, but still get the same error message. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you check the file exists in vendor?

Comment: @MarkRees No, neither of these classes exist in the vendor directory or the app directory.